# Why does this function fail to typecheck?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, parametric-polymorphism

During a lecture on functional programming we saw the following Haskell function:

```
f :: Bool -> Int -> (a -> Int) -> Int
f x y z = if x then y + y else (z x) + (z y)
```

It is expected that this function will fail to typecheck. However, the reason why this happens was not explained. When trying it out in GHCI I got the following output:

```
Prelude> :l test [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs,
interpreted )

test.hs:2:35:
    Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type `Bool'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for f :: Bool -> Int -> (a -> Int) -> Int
          at test.hs:1:6
    Relevant bindings include
      z :: a -> Int (bound at test.hs:2:7)
      f :: Bool -> Int -> (a -> Int) -> Int (bound at test.hs:2:1)
    In the first argument of `z', namely `x'
    In the first argument of `(+)', namely `(z x)' Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Suppose I call `f` like `f True 3 (\n -> n+1)`.  What would you expect to happen?

Comment: Remember that the type `f :: Bool -> Int -> (a -> Int) -> Int` means that the *caller* gets to pick the `a`.  So it perfectly fine for the caller to choose a function with type `String -> Int`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
f :: Bool -> Int -> (a -> Int) -> Int
f x y z = if x then y + y else (z x) + (z y)
```

The type signature asserts that our function `z` is polymorphic in its first argument. It takes a value of any type `a` and returns an `Int`. However, the scoping of the type variable `a` also means that it must be the same type `a` at all uses. `a` cannot be instantiated to different types at the same use site. This is "rank 1 polymoprhism".

You can read the type as really:

```
f :: forall a. Bool -> Int -> (a -> Int) -> Int
```

So:

```
z (x :: Bool) + z (y :: Int)
```

is invalid, as `a` is constrained to two different, independant types.

A language extension allows us to change the scope of `a` so that it can be instantiated to a polymorphic variable -- i.e. to hold different types at the same use site, including to have polymorphic function types:

```
Prelude> :set -XRankNTypes

Prelude> let f :: Bool -> Int -> (forall a . a -> Int) -> Int 
             f x y z = if x then y + y else (z x) + (z y)
```

Now the type `a` doesn't have global scope, and individual instantiations can vary. 
This lets us write the "more polymorphic" function `f` and use it:

```
Prelude> f True 7 (const 1)
14
```

So that's how cool higher rank polymorphism is. More code reuse.

Comment: I think this answer confuses a little, as it doesn't work even for this `(z x) + (z x)`, where z is applied with the same type.

Comment: Hmm? `f :: Bool -> Int -> (forall a . a -> Int) -> Int ; f x y z = if x then y + y else (z x) + (z x)` is perfectly well-typed with rank N.

Comment: Typechecks well with rank N. But the statement `a is constrained to two different, independent types.` is a little confusing because even if `a` was constrained to a single type `(z x + z x)`, it doesn't compile with the default Rank 1.

Comment: Or to be more clear, your answer suggests that because at the use site we have instantiated it with different types (`Bool` and `Int`) it doesn't work. But that is not the case, It doesn't work even if instantiated with a single type i.e `(z x + z x)`.

Comment: Indeed, that sentence seems to imply that `f x y z = if x then y + y then z y` , applying `z` only to one argument, would pass type-checking with the original signature. This is not the case, though.

Answer (score 3):

That is simply not how simple parametric polymorphism works.  The function `z` is polymorphic in the signature of the function, but in the body its only monomorphic.

When type-checking the definition the type checker infers a monomorphic type for the type variable `a` to use throughout the definition of the function.  Your `f` however tries to call `z` with two different types, and thus the type checker infers two conflicting types for `a`.

Answer (score 2):

Even

```
f :: Bool -> Int -> (a -> Int) -> Int
f x y z = if x then y + y else (z y) + (z y)
```

wouldn't typecheck (as was pointed out in the comments), and generate the same error, because Haskell infers *least general types* for expressions, and your type is more general than the inferred. As ["A Gentle Introduction to Haskell"](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/goodies.html) puts it,

> An expression's or function's principal type is the least general type that, intuitively, "contains all instances of the expression".

If you specify a type explicitly, Haskell assumes you did that for a reason, and insists on matching the inferred type to the given type.

For the expression above the inferred type is `(Num t) => Bool -> t -> (t -> t) -> t`, so when matching the types, it sees that you gave `Int` for `y` and the type of `z` becomes `(Int -> Int)`. Which is *less* general than `(a -> Int)`. But *you* insisted on having an `a` there (not an `Int`) — a *rigid* type variable. In other words, your function `f` can only accept functions of type `Int -> Int`, but you are insisting that it may be given *any* function `:: a -> Int`, including `:: String -> Int` etc. (as @augustsson points out in the comments). Your declared type is too broad.

Similarly, if you had just one `(z x)` it would match with the given type of `x` and arrive at the narrower than declared type `(Bool -> Int)` for the `z` function. And yet again complain about a rigid type variable.

In effect, you declared the type `(Num t) => Bool -> t -> (t1 -> t) -> t` but it really is `(Num t) => Bool -> t -> (t -> t) -> t`. It is a different type.

Comment: I realized that and reverted back with `a`. :)

Comment: ah, just saw it. :) thanks for bringing up that example, that clarifies the issue.